# QuickBlox JS in Node Environment

Tags: node.js, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox in a node environment, which does not have XMLHttpRequest by default, so I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at i (quickblox.min.js:2380:1)
```

Also installing `xhr2` does not help.

Is there way to make QuickBlox work for node?

Answer (score 0):

Use alternative npm for make http calls

Here, "axios" npm.

The axios package is also universal and can be used on the browser and on the server.

First, install the module:

```
npm install axios
```

Now you are able to use it:

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function getUser() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api/');

    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

console.log(await getUser());
```

Comment: I would have to change the quickblox library for this